# Creating Remedy tickets through API

Tags: automation, remedy

Has anyone implemented or explored APIs to create tickets in Remedy (now BMC Helix ITSM)? We want to automate the CRQ ticket creation process automated through APIs.
Please let me know if you have any ideas as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this](https://docs.bmc.com/docs/ars91/en/bmc-remedy-ar-system-rest-api-overview-609071509.html) article?
For on premises installation :

```
The REST API uses the base URI for the web service, such as:
- https://<localhost>:<port>/api/{namespace}/{version}
```

After understanding the "API login information" you will be able to trigger e.g. incident/change/wo creation from the API Post call as this one:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://<localhost>:<port>/api/arsys/v1/entry/HPD:IncidentInterface_Create?fields=values(Incident Number)' \
--header 'Authorization: AR-JWT keyHere' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "values": {
      "Internet E-mail":"tester@test.com",
    "Description": "REST API: Incident Creation",
    "Detailed_Decription": "REST API: Incident Creation",
    "Urgency": "3-Medium",
    "Status": "New",
    "Reported Source": "Email",
    "Service_Type": "User Service Restoration"
  }
}'
```

Inside the response body of this call you will see the created ticket ID for your reference.